# Request body has value but I can't access it

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am currently doing some user signup from angular2 front end to express back end. Everything is working fine except on getting the values from the request body. Take a look at this.

usersRoute.js

```
userRouter.route('/signup')
    .post(function(req, res){
      console.log(req.body);
      mongoose.connect(url, function(err){
        var user = {
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password,
          firstname: req.body.firstname,
          lastname: req.body.lastname,
          gender: req.body.gender,
          address: req.body.address,
          contact: req.body.contact,
          email: req.body.email
        };
        console.log(user);
        users.create(user, function(err, results){
          // res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/login');

          //tobeChanged
          console.log(results);
          mongoose.disconnect();
        });
      });
    });
```

On the first console.log I am trying to look if there is a value on the req.body and then on the second console.log is when I am trying to see if the *user* variable got some value. This is what happens.

[image]

as we can see, *user* variable has no value but I am accessing it through req.body.*name*. Can someone help me clarify this?

OPTIONAL QUESTION: Those \n is bothering me. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Could you replace your console.log(req.body); with a loop over the object properties like for(var p in body.req){console.log(p))}; to confirm what properties req.body actually has? it would look like it has one single property named after everything that stands in between the first pair of apostrophes that span over the first three lines, with a null value.

Comment: I did the loop and it displays all the values. kindly look at this http://prntscr.com/dkf65g the first console log is the loop. the second console log is for the user variable and the third undefined is for the results in callback.

Comment: I think the first block of key / value pairs is actually printed as one single output block - just as I hinted at. But this is not necessarily evident to see. Put a counter in your loop like

var i = 0; for(var p in body.req){i++}; console.log(i);

This will most likely spit out 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:

Here your request object's scope is different. you want to use request object in function callback.

> So one thing you can do is passing that value which calling callback.

Solution: 
Change this

`mongoose.connect(url, function(err){`

To this

`mongoose.connect(url, function(err,req){`

Hope this will help.Thanks

Comment: i still got undefined. i also put the user outside the callback also no luck.

Comment: my bad can you try and check with this mongoose.connect(url, req,function(err){

Comment: somehow I got it working. Before, I appended a header with x-www-form-urlencoded. I changed it to application/json and it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try declare the `user` object outside of the callback.

```
.post(function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  var user = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      gender: req.body.gender,
      address: req.body.address,
      contact: req.body.contact,
      email: req.body.email
    };
    mongoose.connect(url, function(err){...
```

If it not work, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bring the data in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some library like body-parser to do this. The fix would be adding the following lines of code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

and change the first two lines of your code as the following:

```
userRouter.route('/signup')
.post(urlencodedParser,function(req, res){
```

The reason for this is the body of the http post request is not extracted by express and hence another library like body-parser is required to perform the task.